# PDF to PNG with high resolution

Tags: c#, ghostscript

I want to convert a PDF file to PNG, I want the output to be 595*842 with high resolution,

I used this command:

> gswin64.exe -q -sDEVICE=png16m  -dSAFER -dMaxBitmap=1000000000
>   -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4  -dPDFFitPage=true -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=C:\cover.png C:\cover.pdf

I know that I can use `-r300` but it will change the dimension to 2479*3509
also, I've tried `-sPAPERSIZE=a4 + -r300` which didn't work.

How can I have the output in 595x842 with high resolution?

Current code:

```
ProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo( "gswin64.exe", "-q -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=C:\\Users\\MNiyatkhair\\Desktop\\cairoCopy\\cover.png C:\\Users\\MNiyatkhair\\Desktop\\cairoCopy\\Holding.pdf" ); 
// -r300 
ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = true; 
ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo); Process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: What does "with high resolution" mean? How is it different from 595*842? What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: my code is like this now: 
            ProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("gswin64.exe", "-q -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=C:\\Users\\MNiyatkhair\\Desktop\\cairoCopy\\cover.png C:\\Users\\MNiyatkhair\\Desktop\\cairoCopy\\Holding.pdf");
            // -r300
            ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
            Process.WaitForExit();

Comment: i want the dimension of the png to be 595*842

Comment: It sounds like you just want to know how to make your PDF render to 595x842. Did you try `-r72`?

Comment: if I don't specify resolution, the png file will be 595*842, but I want a higher resolution with the same dimension and -r72 don't change any thing.

Comment: I'll ask you again. What does "high resolution" mean?

Comment: after converting to png when you do zoom in 595*842, you can tell that it doesn't have a good quality, but when you use -r300 and you zoom in the png it has a good quality

Comment: If you want 595x842, you can't have good quality. If you want good quality, you have to have resolution higher than 595x842. You can't have both.

Comment: 595x842 is your resolution and that and especially high. When you zoom in on a PDF it's probably mostly vector graphics in it so it can be rendered depending on your zoom level but with a PNG you just got the pixels to start with and that won't look good when you zoom in unless you got enough pixels.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to increase the image resolution (for example -r(72*3)) and add proportional downscale factor **-dDownScaleFactor=3**. It will work like native PDF MatrixTransform.